# Apply function with nested if statement R

Tags: r, apply

So I understand how the `apply` function should be used but I am not sure how to integrate with an `IF` statement. Here is my attempt and can someone please push me in the right direction:

```
data <- mtcars
    apply(data, 1, function(x) {
      if (data$mpg < 20) {
      data$colour <- "blue"
      } else {
      data$colour <- "red"
      }
    })
```

I just want to add a column to `data` for each row of the data frame for values in `data$mpg` between certain ranges.

Comment: Please add a sample of your expected output.

Comment: I think you need `sapply` not `apply` or `apply` within a margin of 2, applying on `mpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using vectorization, which is preferred in R due to its speed:

```
data <- mtcars
data$colour <- ifelse(data$mpg < 20, data$colour <- "blue", data$colour <- "red")
```

This yields the following data.frame:

```
            mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb colour
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    red
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    red
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    red
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    red
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   blue
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   blue
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4   blue
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2    red
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2    red
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   blue
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4   blue
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   blue
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3   blue
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   blue
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4   blue
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4   blue
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4   blue
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1    red
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2    red
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1    red
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1    red
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2   blue
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2   blue
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4   blue
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2   blue
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1    red
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2    red
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2    red
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4   blue
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6   blue
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8   blue
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2    red
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` based option using `within`:

```
 head(within(mtcars,{
      my_col <-ifelse(mpg < 20, "blue", "red")
        }),3)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
              my_col
Mazda RX4        red
Mazda RX4 Wag    red
Datsun 710       red
```

Or with `sapply` which in my experience is a bit faster than `apply`ing at a margin of 2:

```
mtcars$colour<-sapply(mtcars[,"mpg"], function(x) ifelse(x<20,"blue","red"))
#rm(mtcars)
#data(mtcars)
#restores mtcars^^
```